# Vue 2 Testing with Mocha, wrapper data is not changing or updating

Tags: vue.js, unit-testing, mocha.js, chai

I'm trying to integrate tests in a vue 2-cli project,the test framework Mocha and Chai is used. There is a very helpful guide I'm relying on:

https://www.dotnetcurry.com/vuejs/1441/vuejs-unit-testing

Most of the tests are working, but every time I'm changing the data on the fly and expecting the changes on the wrapper, the wrapper is not updated at all. For example:

```
describe('the onIncrease method', () => {
    let wrapper;
    let componentInstance;
    beforeEach(() => {
        wrapper = shallowMount(Counter, {
            propsData: {initialValue: 42},
        });
        componentInstance = wrapper.vm;
    });

    it('the counter value is increased by one', () => {
        componentInstance.onIncrease();
        expect(componentInstance.value).to.be.equal(43);
    });
    // this test passes and returns the correct 43
    it('the rendered output contains the value increased by one', () => {
        componentInstance.onIncrease();
        expect(wrapper.text()).to.include('Counter value: 43');
    });
    // this test fails with:
    // expected 'Counter value: 42' to include 'Counter value: 43'
});
```

I'm working on this for days and hopefully anyone can give a hint on how to get the updated data. There is a picture of the error-page, maybe it's useful.

[image]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The Issue is solved, it failed because of bad timing.

try to set a timer or use the nextTick() function: https://v3.vuejs.org/api/global-api.html#nexttick

Answer (score 0):

I don't think that this is possible at all. You can set the default properties and render the component, but after that you only can change and read the data and computed properties, at least in unit testing.

Comment: Thanks for your answer. But I saw a snippet in github which was working, and the article mentioned it working to.